# Get file size using opencsv, android studio 2.1

Tags: java, android-studio, export-to-csv, opencsv

I'm trying to export a CSV file with the help of **opencsv 3.7**. I need to limit the size of my file and I didn't figure how to do it yet. `file.size()` doesn't help in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a custom `FileOutputStream` that counts bytes written by it's `write()` method and close the stream if the maximum is reached.

Or you can ask the stream before writing the next csv-line to determine if there is still room.

Also take into account the file-encoding (do you want to count bytes, or characters?)

Comment: im very new to all of this, i want it to count bytes